# what's the difference between ::= and := in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, colon-equals

This is impossible to search on google, bing, yahoo, etc, because it uses symbols.  How annoying!

What's the difference between `::=` and `:=` in oracle's pl/sql?

Comment: Do you have an actual Oracle code sample which uses `::=`?  If so, please post it.

Comment: There is no `::=` standard operator in Oracle SQL or in PL/SQL. I suppose that someone might have defined `::=` as a user-defined operator (see [CREATE OPERATOR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6004.htm#i2064967)) but having never done it I'm not sure how this would work. [SQL operator reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators.htm#SQLRF003).  [PL/SQL operator reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/index.htm#OP). Please edit your question and include a code sample. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Meaning of `:=` is easily (?) found from Oracle documentation [PL/SQL Language Fundamentals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#CIHJCJAD). You can also observe that PL/SQL doesn't have such a built-in delimiter as `::=`. I agree with comments of @APC and @BobJarvis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure about ::= as I have not seen that in Oracle but the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign#In_computer_programming) says about :=

> In computer programming languages, the equals sign typically denotes
>   either a boolean operator to test equality of values (e.g. as in
>   Pascal or Eiffel), which is consistent with the symbol's usage in
>   mathematics, or an assignment operator (e.g. as in C-like languages).
>   Languages making the former choice often use a colon-equals (:=) or ≔
>   to denote their assignment operator. Languages making the latter
>   choice often use a double equals sign (==) to denote their boolean
>   equality operator.

Also check [here](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/Oracle-11g-PL/SQL-Basics):

> The assignment operator in PL/SQL is a **colon plus an equal sign
>   (:=)**. PL/SQL string literals are delimited by single quotes

Answer (score 3):

The only place (that I'm aware of) where `::=` is used is in the syntactical description of <kbd>[PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_syntx001.htm#SQLRF55485)</kbd> (or any other language, for that matter) using Backus-Naur Form (BNF). The `::=` symbol is a part of the BNF descriptive language itself, not a part of the language being described. There are many tutorials for BNF -- have fun!

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196066/what-does-a-double-colon-followed-by-an-equals-sign-mean-in-programming-do

Comment: Almost all Oracle SQL tutorials are [using BNF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm). Thank you !